# time.Millisecond * int confusion

Tags: go

In the below example, if the 1000's are both int's (which I think they are) why would the bottom fail to compile?

```
//works
time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)

//fails
var i = 1000
time.Sleep(i * time.Millisecond)
```

Comment: Show us the error message.

Comment: Error message: `invalid operation: i * time.Millisecond (mismatched types int and time.Duration)`.

Comment: @Kavu huh... it surprises me the former works, then

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334542/golang-why-can-i-type-alias-functions-and-use-them-without-casting

Comment: @nemo: How is it related?

Comment: @peterSO they both address unnamed type conversion. The answer to the linked question explains it more generally though.

Comment: @nemo: The answer to the question does not involve unnamed type conversions: [Operators](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Operators). The types in the question are named types: int, time.Duration, int64.

Comment: @peterSO: Ah, you're right. I mixed up unnamed types and untyped constants. Sorry.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> [Operators](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Operators)
>
> Operators combine operands into expressions.
>
> Comparisons are discussed elsewhere. For other binary operators, the
> operand types must be identical unless the operation involves shifts
> or untyped constants. For operations involving constants only, see the
> section on constant expressions.
>
> Except for shift operations, if one operand is an untyped constant and
> the other operand is not, the constant is converted to the type of the
> other operand.

For example, using the "`*`" (multiplication) operator,

```
package main

import (
    "time"
)

func main() {

    // works - 1000 is an untyped constant
    // which is converted to type time.Duration
    time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)

    // fails - v is a variable of type int
    // which is not identical to type time.Duration
    var v = 1000
    // invalid operation: i * time.Millisecond (mismatched types int and time.Duration)
    time.Sleep(v * time.Millisecond)
}
```

Possible solution: 
Convert `i` to `time.Duration` (which underneath is an `int64`). (as suggested by @lcapra)

```
var i = 1000
time.Sleep(time.Duration(i) * time.Millisecond)
```

Comment: So then does this mean if you defined `v` as an untyped constant `const v = 1000 ` it would work?

Answer (score 24):

You should convert to `time.Duration` (which underneath is an `int64`)

```
var i = 1000
time.Sleep(time.Duration(i) * time.Millisecond)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make `i` a constant instead of a variable, if you are primarily interested in naming the value:

```golang
package main

import (
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // works:
    time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)

    // works also:
    const i = 1000
    time.Sleep(i * time.Millisecond)
}
```

In-reply-to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19338130/11630268

Answer (score 1):

Go won't convert numeric types automatically for you. As far as I understand, 1000 isn't a numeric type until defined as one.

**The language specification says:**

> Conversions are required when different numeric types are mixed in an expression or assignment. For instance, int32 and int are not the same type even though they may have the same size on a particular architecture.

Comment: `1000` is an untyped numeric constant. [Constants](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants)

Answer (score -2):

Both operants need to be of the same type time.Duration. You can use time.Sleep(v * time.Millisecond).