# Create method for map[string]interface{} in Go

Tags: json, interface, go, assert, unmarshalling

I have defined a Type

```
type UnknownMapString map[string]interface{}
```

I also have methods for them like so

```
func (m UnknownMapString) Foo() {
    fmt.Println("test!")
}
```

I get a panic when running:

> interface conversion: interface is map[string]interface {}, not
>   main.UnknownMapString

The map[string]interface{} is unmarshaled from JSON input.

Playground replicating it -> http://play.golang.org/p/kvw4dcZVNH

I thought that you could not have interface as a receiver of method so we needed to type assert (not convert?) to a Named Type and use that Named Type as the receiver of the method. 
Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
val = val.(UnknownMapString)
```

This is a [type assertion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions), which supposes the [named type](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Types) `UnknownMapString` is identical to the unnamed type `map[string]interface{}`.
And [type identity](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity) tells us that:

> A named and an unnamed type are always different.

But: you [can **assign**](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) a `map[string]interface{}` to a `UnknownMapString` because

> `x` is assignable to a variable of type `T` ("`x` is assignable to `T`") when:
>
> `x`'s type `V` and `T` have identical underlying types and at least one of `V` or `T` is not a named type.

This would work:

```
var val2 UnknownMapString  = val.(map[string]interface{})
val2.Foo()
```

`val2` is not an unnamed type, and both `val2` and `val.(map[string]interface{})` underlying types are identical.

<kbd>[play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/QyNRwtZPBa)</kbd>

Output:

```
test!
```

Comment: Thanks, so there is no way to have the original interface{} `val` equal the `UnknownMapString` type variable? Also, `map[string]interface{}` is unnamed because it composes type from existing types?

GoDocs say unnamed "composes a new type from existing types". Existing types mean ONLY built in types and not a defined type that I make correct?

Comment: @AnsonL yes, no way. `map[string]interface{}` is unnamed because it simply is a description corresponding to how that type is to be structured.

Comment: @AnsonL so you need to work with `var val2 UnknownMapString`, not directly with `val`.

Comment: "A description corresponding to how type is structured"? So `map[string]interface{}` is unnamed because how it is structured because creators of Go made it that way? Am I correct in assuming that **only** built in types of ArrayType, StructType, PointerType, FunctionType, InterfaceType, SliceType, MapType, ChannelType are unnamed?

Comment: @AnsonL you can see more at http://stackoverflow.com/a/19334952/6309 and http://golang.org/ref/spec#Types: named types are specified by a (possibly qualified) type name; unnamed types are specified using a type literal, which composes a new type from existing types. You need a **identifier**, the type name, to bind to a type.