# Go: Extending unnamed types such as []string

Tags: go

I am a bit confused in regards to type aliases in Go.

I have read this related SO question - [Why can I type alias functions and use them without casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334542/golang-why-can-i-type-alias-functions-and-use-them-without-casting).

As far as I understand, unnamed and named variables are assignable to each other if the underlying structure is the same.

What I am trying to figure out, is can I extend unnamed types by naming them - something like this:

```
type Stack []string

func (s *Stack) Print() {
    for _, a := range s {
        fmt.Println(a)
    }
}
```

This gives me the error `cannot range over s (type *Stack)`
Tried casting it to `[]string`, no go.

I know the below code works - is this the way I should do it? If so, I would love to know why the above is not working, and what is the use of declarations such as `type Name []string`.

```
type Stack struct {
    data []string
}

func (s *Stack) Print() {
    for _, a := range s.data {
        fmt.Println(a)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `for _, a := range *s` ?

Comment: `s` is a pointer to `Stack` and thus a pointer to `[]string` and in Go you cannot range over pointers. A `range *s` would do. This has nothing to do with "named" or "unnamed" types or aliases, it is just a result of static typing and your s having the wrong type for range-ing.

Comment: **In Go, there is no such thing as a type alias.** The `type` keyword introduces new named types. They are not aliases. (This is one of Go's important strengths compared to various other languages)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should dereference the pointer s

```
type Stack []string

func (s *Stack) Print() {
    for _, a := range *s {
        fmt.Println(a)
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! So simple. For some reason, I looked for the complicated solution. I guess it is because the Go compiler spoiled me - it usually lets me know when `*type` is used as `type`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Francesc Campoy (Google) has a great presentation where he summarizes in which cases you can use *T or T and when it is different. https://speakerdeck.com/campoy/things-i-learned-teaching-go starting in page 38.