# Design decision in Go's interface{}

Tags: interface, go, type-conversion

Why Go doesn't automatically convert between:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Any interface{} // Any is an empty interface
type X func(x Any) // X is a function that receives Any

func Y(x X) { // Y is a function that receives X
  x(1)
}

func test(v interface{}) { // test is not considered equal to X
  fmt.Println("called",v)
}

func main() {
  Y(test) // error: cannot use test (type func(interface {})) as type X in argument to Y
}
```

Also this one:

```
package main
import "fmt"

type Any interface{}

func X2(a Any) {
  X(a)
} 
func Y2(a interface{}) {
  X2(a) // this is OK
}

func X(a ...Any) {
  fmt.Println(a)
}
func Y(a ...interface{}) { // but this one not ok
  X(a...) // error: cannot use a (type []interface {}) as type []Any in argument to X
}

func main() {
  v := []int{1,2,3}
  X(v)
  Y(v)
}
```

I was really hopeful that `interface{}` could be renamed to `Any` on anything (`slices`, `map`, `func`) not just simple types

Second question would be: is there a way to make it possible?

Comment: The lack of implicit casts between named<->unnamed probably feels inconvenient right here. It does mean, though that if you pass both filesizes and flags as `int64`s, you can declare `type Flags uint64` so that the type system will catch if you accidentally swap them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one is about [type conversion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) and **[type identity](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity)**, for which you have a set of rules.
See more at "[Why can I type alias functions and use them without casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19334542/6309)"

- `type Any interface{}` is a named type
- `interface{}` is an unnamed type

Their identity is different, and you cannot use `func(interface[})` in place of `func(Any)`.

---

The second one is covered by the [golang faq](https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface)

### Can I convert a `[]T` to an `[]interface{}`?

> Not directly, because **they do not have the same representation in memory**.
>   It is necessary to copy the elements individually to the destination slice. This example converts a slice of int to a slice of interface{}:

```
t := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
s := make([]interface{}, len(t))
for i, v := range t {
    s[i] = v
}
```

See "[what is the meaning of `interface{}` in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23148998/6309)" for more on the memory representation:

[image: interface]