# Golang underlying types

Tags: types, go

In this code snippet from the spec

```
type T1 string
type T2 T1
type T3 []T1
type T4 T3
```

The spec says:

> The underlying type of string, `T1`, and `T2` is `string`.
>   The underlying type of `[]T1`, `T3`, and `T4` is `[]T1`.

Why is the underlying type of `T2` not `T1`, but `string`?
Shouldn't the underlying type of `T4` instead be `[]string` and not `[]T1` if the underlying type of `T1` is `string`?
Confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [spec mentions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types):

> Each type `T` has an underlying type: If `T` is one of the predeclared boolean, numeric, or string types, **or a type literal**, the corresponding underlying type is `T` itself.
> **Otherwise, `T`'s underlying type is the underlying type of the type to which `T` refers in its type declaration**.

`T2` refers in its type declaration to `T1`, which has the underlying type `string`.

It is important for the underlying type of `T2` to be `string`, because it will help for [Assignability](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) where

> A value x is assignable to a variable of type T ("x is assignable to T")
> x's type V and T have identical underlying types and at least one of V or T is not a [named type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types).

This is also detailed in "[Golang: Why can I type alias functions and use them without casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19334952/6309)"

---

When it comes to the underlying type of `T4`, we are talking about an underlying unnamed type `[]T1`.

And again, the assignability rule says you can assign `[]T1` to T4 (since `[]T1` is not a named type): its underlying type stops at the first not-named type (`[]T1`).

See [this example on playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Bt3dKBB63L)

```
var t3 T3 = []T1{"a", "b"}
fmt.Println("t3='%+v'", t3)
// var t4 T4 = []string{}
// cannot use []string literal (type []string) as type T4 in assignment
var t4 T4 = T4(t3)
fmt.Println("t4='%+v'", t4)
t4 = []T1{T1("c"), T1("d")}
fmt.Println("t4='%+v'", t4)
```

Output:

```
t3='%+v' [a b]
t4='%+v' [a b]
t4='%+v' [c d]
```

---

[Danny Rivers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12885875/danny-rivers) adds in the comments:

> Why is the underlying type of `T4` equal to `[]T1`, not `[]string`?
>
> The underlying type of `T4` is defined to be the underlying of `T3`, which is underlying (`[]T1`), and since `[]T1` is a **type literal**, that is as far down as it goes.
> The language of the spec makes it easy to miss that TYPE LITERALS, not just pre-declared types, count as an underlying type.

Comment: I am so lost I created a generic with a slice constraint but when I pass a slice it does implement it why?

Comment: @Agyakwalf Could you show your code in a separate question (with a link back to this one)? that way, others can comment on it.

Comment: I am ok ,now ... I think I am getting the hang of the generics

Comment: @Agyakwalf Great, well done. Good reads on this topic: [Revisiting arrays and slices with generics](https://quii.gitbook.io/learn-go-with-tests/go-fundamentals/revisiting-arrays-and-slices-with-generics), [A generic approach to check if an element is present in an array/slice](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-write-generic-helper-functions-with-go-d47c52986016), [slice of bytes](https://twitter.com/go100and1/status/1536892875450880000), ... 1/2

Comment: @Agyakwalf 2/2 [Why slice doens't work more nicely with Generics?](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/s9pf2w/why_slice_doenst_work_more_nicely_with_generics/), [generic slice examples](https://gosamples.dev/tags/generics-intro/).

Comment: Nice explanation. Once I realised that in `Each type T has an underlying type: If T is one of the predeclared boolean, numeric, or string types, or a type literal`, type literal is []T1, `[]int`, `map[string]int` I understood what an underlying type.

Also I'm guessing that `Each type T has an underlying type: If T is one of the predeclared boolean, numeric, or string types, or a type literal, the corresponding underlying type is T itself.` is true because these types are primitive types?

Comment: @bit Yes. You also find them presented in [this section](https://kuree.gitbooks.io/the-go-programming-language-report/content/3/text.html).

Comment: @VonC thanks. Is a pointer part of these types whose underlying type is itself?

Comment: @bit You can declare a [pointer to an underlying type](https://go101.org/article/pointer.html): `*int  // An unnamed pointer type whose base type is int.`. More on [underlying types here](https://go101.org/article/type-system-overview.html#underlying-type).

Comment: @VonC thanks for the links. Are the two websites you linked trustworthy sources for becoming an expert in Go?

Comment: @bit Mostly the second one, managed by [Tapir Liui](https://twitter.com/TapirLiu/) is a great resource. Its [twitter account](https://twitter.com/go100and1) is very active.

Comment: I was still confused after reading both question & answer, with this question: 

Why is the underlying type of T4 equal to []T1, not []string?

I figured it out:

The underlying type of T4 is defined to be the underlying of T3, which is underlying ([]T1), and since []T1 is a type literal, thats as far down as it goes. The language of the spec makes it easy to miss that TYPE LITERALS, not just predeclared types, count as an underlying type.

Comment: @DannyRivers Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Can we say underlying type of "type xyz struct { var str string }" is string

Comment: @Tarun No, the underlying type of `xyz` is the entire `struct` type literal. The field within the struct `var` is of type `string`, but that doesn't mean the underlying type of the entire struct `xyz` is `string`. The underlying type is the entire structure, not just one of its fields.