# Why are you unable convert Slice types?

Tags: go, type-conversion, slice, type-alias

I was wondering why you can't do:

```
type Foo struct { A int }
type Bar Foo

foos := []Foo{Foo{1}, Foo{2}}
bars := []Bar(foos)
//cannot convert foos (type []Foo) to type []Bar
```

and I found out that this would require the runtime to perform a loop over the slice to convert each of the elements, which would be non-idiomatic Go. This makes sense.

However, could this not be solved by the compiler just aliasing `Bar` as `Foo`, so internally they're the same and they use the same type header underneath? I'm guessing the answer is no though I'm curious as to why.

Comment: You're essentially asking how to work around the type system to optimise out a loop. I think the [`unsafe`](http://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/) package would allow you to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
[]Bar(foos)
```

is a type [conversion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions). Conversions have specific rules according to the spec:

> A non-constant value `x` can be converted to type `T` in any of these cases:
>
> - `x` is [assignable](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) to `T`.
> - `x`'s type and `T` have identical underlying types.
> - `x`'s type and `T` are unnamed pointer types and their pointer base types have identical underlying types.
> - `x`'s type and `T` are both integer or floating point types.
> - `x`'s type and `T` are both complex types.
> - `x` is an integer or a slice of bytes or runes and `T` is a string type.
> - `x` is a string and `T` is a slice of bytes or runes.

None applies here. Why?

**Because the underlying type of `[]Foo` is not the same as the underlying type of `[]Bar`.** And a value of type `[]Foo` is not assignable to a variable of type `[]Bar`, see [Assignability rules here](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability).

The underlying type of `Foo` is the same as the underlying type of `Bar`, but the same does not apply to slices where the element type is `Foo` and `Bar`.

So the following works:

```
type Foo struct{ A int }

type Foos []Foo
type Bars Foos

func main() {
    foos := []Foo{Foo{1}, Foo{2}}
    bars := Bars(foos)

    fmt.Println(bars)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/qe6wtzkVCy)):

```
[{1} {2}]
```

Note that since the actual memory representation of `Foo` and `Bar` is the same (because the underlying type of `Bar` is `Foo`), in this case using the package [`unsafe`](http://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/) you can "view" a value of `[]Foo` as a value of `[]Bar`:

```
type Foo struct{ A int }
type Bar Foo

func main() {
    foos := []Foo{Foo{1}, Foo{2}}

    bars := *(*[]Bar)(unsafe.Pointer(&foos))

    fmt.Println(bars)
    fmt.Printf("%T", bars)
}
```

This: `*(*[]Bar)(unsafe.Pointer(&foos))` means that take the address of `foos`, convert it to [`unsafe.Pointer`](http://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Pointer) ([according to spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_unsafe) all pointers can be converted to `unsafe.Pointer`), then this `Pointer` is converted to `*[]Bar` (again according to the spec `Pointer` can be converted to any other pointer type), and then this pointer is dereferenced (`*` operator), so the result is a value of type `[]Bar` as can be seen in the output.

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/KuzClGFqUc)):

```
[{1} {2}]
[]main.Bar
```

**Notes:**

Quoting the package doc of `unsafe`:

> Package unsafe contains operations that step around the type safety of Go programs.
>
> Packages that import unsafe may be non-portable and are not protected by the Go 1 compatibility guidelines.

What does this mean? It means that you shouldn't revert to using package `usafe` every time it makes your life easier. You should only use it in exceptional cases, when not using it would make your program really slow and complicated.

In your program this is not the case as I proposed a working example with just a little refactoring (`Foos` and `Bars` being slices).

`unsafe` steps around the type safety of Go. What does this mean? If you would change the type of `foos` (e.g. drastically like `foos := "trap!"`), your program would still compile and run, but most likely runtime panic would occur. Using `usafe` you lose type checks of the compiler.

While if you use my other proposal (`Foos` and `Bars`), such changes/typos are detected at compile time.

Comment: Thanks @icza, so the underlying representation is the same, it's just the spec which prevents the conversion - the unsafe conversion was what I was after!

Comment: @jpillora Please see edited answer. Do not use `unsafe` just because it's easier. Please use proper design to avoid using `unsafe` if possible.

Comment: fair enough and agreed - I'm currently looping through to convert each element and I'll only use unsafe if performance suffers which it most likely won't. Maybe it could be avoided completely I guess? The use case is: I'm importing a package `foo` and I'd like to expose its type `foo.Foo` in my package, so I've re-typed it to prevent the need my users to import both my package *and* `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in "[Why can I type alias functions and use them without casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334542/why-can-i-type-alias-functions-and-use-them-without-casting)"

> **In Go, there is no such thing as a type alias**.
>   The `type` keyword introduces new **[named types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types)**. They are not aliases
>
> If you compare two named types, the names must match in order for them to be interchangeable

This is what the [spec mentions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations):

> A type declaration binds an identifier, the type name, to a new type that has the same underlying type as an existing type, and operations defined for the existing type are also defined for the new type.
>   **The new type is different from the existing type**.