# How can I sort Go slices whose element type is an alias of string, but not string itself?

Tags: sorting, types, go

```
type MyObject string
var objects []MyObject
```

I want to sort these objects. The standard library has `sort.Strings`, but that requires an instance of `[]string` instead of `[]MyObject`.

My current solution is to implement `sort.Interface` (as shown below) and use `sort.Sort`, but I'd like to get rid of that boilerplate code. Is there a nicer way?

```
type MyObjects []MyObject

func (objs MyObjects) Len() int {
    return len(objs)
}

func (objs MyObjects) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return strings.Compare(string(objs[i]), string(objs[j])) < 0
}

func (objs MyObjects) Swap(i, j int) {
    o := objs[i]
    objs[i] = objs[j]
    objs[j] = o
}
```

Comment: BTW, the documentation for `strings.Compare` explicitly states you shouldn't normally use it; just do `return objs[i] < objs[j]` (or if that complains then cast them to `string`).

Comment: Also, idiomatic `Swap` would be: `func (p MyObjects) Swap(i, j int) { p[i], p[j] = p[j], p[i] }`

Comment: With those simplifications the [idiomatic way of doing it](https://play.golang.org/p/EcoRDa-M0r) isn't bad at all.

Comment: Lesson learned: I need to write more Go to become more idiomatic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Since Go doesn't allow the implicit conversion of types within slices (there is also no covariance with interfaces), you need to supply the appropriate methods for your type.

```
type MyObjects []MyObject

func (p MyObjects) Len() int           { return len(p) }
func (p MyObjects) Swap(i, j int)      { p[i], p[j] = p[j], p[i] }
func (p MyObjects) Less(i, j int) bool { return p[i] < p[j] }
```

If you *really* want to do this, you could use unsafe (but please don't). I doubt those 3 extra lines of *safe* code are going to make that big a difference for you.

http://play.golang.org/p/d6ciFjjr2c

```
objects := []MyObject{"one", "two", "three", "four"}
sort.Strings(*(*[]string)(unsafe.Pointer(&objects)))
```

Comment: The `p[i], p[j] = p[j], p[i]` notation (thanks for reminding me of that :) and compact function bodies reduce the boilerplate to a bare minimum, so I'll go with that.

Answer (score 1):

*IF* your `MyObject` type is an "alias" with `string` being its underlying type, you can't. See [@JimB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32189675/1705598) here.

The underlying type of `MyObject` is the same as the underlying type of `string` (which is itself: `string`), but the underlying type of `[]MyObject` is not the same as the underlying type of `[]string`.

See further explanations here:

[Conversion of a slice of string into a slice of custom type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29031353/conversion-of-a-slice-of-string-into-a-slice-of-custom-type)

[Why are you unable convert Slice types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31891493/why-are-you-unable-convert-slice-types)

But if you happen to refactor a little your type system, your problems go away:

```
type MyObjects []string

var objects MyObjects

func main() {
    objects = MyObjects{"abc", "aaa"}
    sort.Strings(objects)
    fmt.Println(objects)
}
```

Output (try it on the <kbd>[Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/tM2KhCd1TG)</kbd>):

```
[aaa abc]
```

For convenience, you can even provide a `Sort()` method on it if you want to:

```
func (m MyObjects) Sort() {
    sort.Strings(m)
}
```

And using it:

```
objects = MyObjects{"abc", "aaa"}
objects.Sort()
fmt.Println(objects)
```

(Output is the same.)

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, `type MyObjects []string` is not an option for me. The `MyObject` instances have quite some logic attached to them, so I need the specific type.