# convert function type in Golang

Tags: go

```
// Each type have Error() string method.
// The error built-in interface type is the conventional interface for
// representing an error condition, with the nil value representing no error.
//  type error interface {
//   Error() string
//  }

func (f binFunc) Error() string {
    return "binFunc error"
}

func func_type_convert() {
    var err error
    err = binFunc(add)
    fmt.Println(err)
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

I have two questions about the code above:

- I don't know why the `Error` method executed, when `add` function was converted into `binFunc` type?
- Why the `add` function converted result was able to assign to an err error interface variable?

Comment: Please provide more detailed sample, use https://play.golang.org/ for it. I just not understand you. What is `add`, what is `binFunc`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`error` is an interface:

```
type error interface {
    Error() string
}
```

This means that any type which has a method: `Error() string` fulfills the interface and can be assigned to a variable of type `error`.

`binFunc` has such a method:

```
func (f binFunc) Error() string {
    return "binFunc error"
}
```

New developers in Go sometimes find this confusing because they don't realize it's possible to attach methods to more than just structs. In this case `binFunc` is defined liked this:

```
type binFunc func(int, int) int
```

So the way this works is you are allowed to convert any function which has the same signature: (from the [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types))

> A function type denotes the set of all functions with the same parameter and result types.

So if you create a function `add`:

```
func add(x, y int) int {
    return x + y
}
```

You are allowed to convert this into a `binFunc`:

```
binFunc(add)
```

And because of the `Error` method on `binFunc` we defined above, we are then able to assign this new `binFunc` to a variable of type `error`:

```
var err error
var bf binFunc = binFunc(add)
err = bf
```

`fmt.Println`'s behavior is to call `.Error()` on errors [for you](http://godoc.org/fmt#Print):

> 4. If an operand implements the error interface, the Error method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any).

So to answer your questions:

- The `Error` method is executed because `fmt.Println` looks for arguments of type `error`, invokes `.Error()` and prints the resulting string.
- You are allowed to assign `binFunc`s to `err` because `binFunc` has an `Error` method. You cannot assign `add` directly to `err` because it does not have an `Error` method. But you are allowed to convert `add` to a `binFunc` because they have the same function signature, and by doing so you can then assign it to the `err` variable.

Comment: This post amazingly explained how and why to convert a function to a specific function type. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

go spec dependencies:
[type casting or conversion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions) -> [assignability](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignability) -> [type identity](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_identity)

1. explicit type [casting or conversion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions)

`binFunc` and `func(int, int) int` have same underlying representation.

```
binFunc(add)
```

note, type casting can happen between 2 types that have the same underlying representation. However, their type can be totally different.

```
type MyInt int

func main() {
    var b MyInt = 3
    a := int(b)
    fmt.Println(a, b)
}
```

2. variable assignment

check [type identity](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_identity)

based on type identity rule, `binFunc` is identical to `func(int, int) int`. So you can do **type casting** as below:

> A named type is always different from **any other type**. Otherwise, two types are identical if their underlying type literals are structurally equivalent; that is, they have the same literal structure and corresponding components have identical types.

```
func(int, int) int
```

is type literal, and it's **unnamed**.

```
type binFunc func(int, int) int
```

is a **named type**.

> Predeclared types, defined types, and type parameters are called named types. An alias denotes a named type if the type given in the alias declaration is a named type.

named type is different from others. but here, `binFunc` is compared with the un-named type: their underlying type literals are structurally equivalent, both `func(int, int) int`.

```
var bfunc binFunc = add
```

check [assignability](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignability)

variable of **named type** can be assigned with a value of **unnamed type** providing their underlying type is identical.

You may call this an **implicit type conversion** here, but it's not accurate. At least golang doesn't call this type conversion because the underlying type/representation is the same.

inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25342529/5335565)

### extra words

[type assertion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions) only requires type identity. Therefore, the rule is simpler than type assignability.

Comment: also found this helpful: https://go101.org/article/type-system-overview.html