# How can I prevent a type being used as a map key?

Tags: dictionary, go, struct, key, unique

I have a type that can be used as a map key, but I want to prevent this from occurring. I assumed that if the type contained a private member it wouldn't be possible from other packages, but this appears to work anyway. What's the best way to make the type unusable as a map key?

```
type MyType struct {
    A *A
    b b

    preventUseAsKey ?
}
```

Comment: I have edited [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37916798/6309): you actually can add a kind of `preventUseAsKey` in your struct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't see any benefit of disallowing a type being used as a key. It is just an option which may or may not be used, the type will not be any better or smaller or faster just because you forbid to use it as a map key.

But if you want to do it: [Spec: Map types:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types)

> The [comparison operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators) == and != must be fully defined for operands of the key type; thus the key type must not be a function, map, or slice.

So if you can violate the terms of the [comparison operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators), you implicitly get what you want. You have a `struct`, terms for the `struct` types:

> Struct values are comparable if all their fields are comparable. Two struct values are equal if their corresponding non-[blank](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier) fields are equal.

So `struct` values are only comparable (and thus can only be used as keys in maps) if all their fields are comparable. **Simply add a field whose type is not comparable.**

> Slice, map, and function values are not comparable.

So for example add a field whose type is a slice, and you're done:

```
type MyType struct {
    S             string
    i             int
    notComparable []int
}
```

Attempting to use the above `MyType` as a key:

```
m := map[MyType]int{}
```

You get a compile-time error:

```
invalid map key type MyType
```

**Note:**

I wrote about not having any benefit of forbidding the type being a key. It's more than that: from now on you won't be able to use comparison operators on values of your type anymore (because of the extra, non-comparable field), so e.g. you lose the option to compare those values:

```
p1, p2 := MyType{}, MyType{}
fmt.Println(p1 == p2)
```

Compile-time error:

```
invalid operation: p1 == p2 (struct containing []int cannot be compared)
```

Note that with a little trick you could still preserve the comparable nature of your type, e.g. by not exporting your type but a wrapper type which embeds the original one; and add the extra, non-comparable type to the wrapper type, e.g.:

```
type myType struct {
    S string
    i int
}

type MyType struct {
    myType
    notComparable []int
}

func main() {
    p1, p2 := MyType{}, MyType{}
    fmt.Println(p1.myType == p2.myType)
}
```

This way your `myType` can remain comparable but still prevent the exported, wrapper `MyType` type to be used as key type.

Answer (score 4):

Your type should [not be comparable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators) in order to be unfit as a map key.

> Slice, map, and function values are not comparable

See [Key Type](https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action#TOC_5.):

> Notably absent from the list are slices, maps, and functions; these types cannot be compared using `==`, and may not be used as map keys.

So if your type is a slice, map or function, you should get what you need.
It could be an "alias" (defining a new [named type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19334952/6309)):

```
type StringSliceWrap []string
type MyFunc func(i int)
```

That alias would not be used as a map key.

---

Update 2017: [Brad Fitzpatrick give this tip](https://twitter.com/bradfitz/status/860145039573385216) (adding a slice in your `struct`) to make sure your type `struct` is *not* comparable: See [play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/tkE2lH6AlQ):

```
package main

// disallowEqual is an uncomparable type.
// If you place it first in your struct, you prevent == from
// working on your struct without growing its size. (Don't put it
// at the end; that grows the size of the struct)
type disallowEqual [0]func()

type T struct {
    _ disallowEqual
    Foo string
    Bar int
}

func main() {
    var t1 T
    var t2 T
    println(t1 == t2)
}
```

`T` cannot be used as amp key now!