# Why can I not use func literal as custom func type despite matching parameters in golang?

Tags: go, middleware, grpc

Package `google.golang.org/grpc` defines type `UnaryClientInterceptor` as:

```
type UnaryClientInterceptor func(ctx context.Context, method string, req, reply interface{}, cc *ClientConn, invoker UnaryInvoker, opts ...CallOption) error
```

In my code I'd like to do something like:

```
func clientInterceptor() grpc.UnaryClientInterceptor {
    return func(ctx context.Context, method string, req, reply interface{}, cc *grpc.ClientConn, invoker grpc.UnaryInvoker, opts ...grpc.CallOption) error {
        //intercept stuff
        return invoker(ctx, method, req, reply, cc, opts...)
    }
}
```

However I get this error:

"cannot use func literal (type func("context".Context, string, interface {}, interface {}, *grpc.ClientConn, grpc.UnaryInvoker, ...grpc.CallOption) error) as type grpc.UnaryClientInterceptor in return argument"

Looking at [Why can I type alias functions and use them without casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334542/why-can-i-type-alias-functions-and-use-them-without-casting) I get the impression that the anonymous function returned in my `clientInterceptor()` should match the `grpc.ClientInterceptor` type.

Also, from the spec on Type Identity (http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity)

> Two function types are identical if they have the same number of parameters and result values, corresponding parameter and result types are identical, and either both functions are variadic or neither is. Parameter and result names are not required to match.

I've tried casting and making variables of type `grpc.UnaryClientInterceptor` but nothing works.

I also did essentially the exact same thing with the `grpc.UnaryServerInterceptor` and had no problems.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It looks kosher so my first guess would be you're referencing the `context` package differently than your version of `grpc`. That package, as of the Go 1.7 moved `context` from `golang.org/x/net/context` to just `context`, and the compiler likely doesn't see them as equivalent.

Comment: That was right! I could not see that at all, thank you. Post an answer so I can mark it correct.

Comment: Glad it worked out! Posted as an answer for the benefit of future Google searches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may be referencing the `context` package differently than your version of `grpc`. As of Go 1.7, the package moved from `golang.org/x/net/context` to just `context`, and the compiler likely doesn't see them as equivalent.