# Why Type Alias and Type behave differently when calling embedded field's methods in Go?

Tags: go

go version go1.11.2 linux/amd64

https://play.golang.org/p/kTvcsWkJeaZ

```
package main

type T1 struct {
}

func (T1) Hello(T1) {
}

type T2 struct {
    T1
}

func (T2) Hello(T2) {
}

type T3 T2
type T4 = T2

func main() {
    var v_T3 T3
    v_T3.Hello(v_T3)
    var v_T4 T4
    v_T4.Hello(v_T4)
}
```

`prog.go:21:12: cannot use v_T3 (type T3) as type T1 in argument to v_T3.T1.Hello`

row 21:I expect call `v_T3.Hello` but the actual call `v_T3.T1.Hello`

row 23:it's ok

Comment: because T3 and T2 are different types. https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334542/why-can-i-type-alias-functions-and-use-them-without-casting

Answer (score 1):

```
type T4 = T2
```

This gives an additional name T4 to the existing type T2. It does not introduce a new type. In other words, T2 and T4 are always interchangeable. That should explain why the `v_T4.Hello(v_T4)` call works. All of the following calls are all synonymous in terms of types (but ignoring that v_T2 and v_T4 are different *values*):

```
var v_T2 T2
var v_T4 T4

v_T2.Hello(v_T2)
v_T2.Hello(v_T4)
v_T4.Hello(v_T2)
v_T4.Hello(v_T4)
```

---

```
type T3 T2
```

This defines a new type T3 that is distinct from all other types. According to the type rules, [T3 doesn't inherit T2's methods](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions). But because they have the same underlying type, T3's and T2's fields are the same, including the embedded T1. This in turn [promotes T1's methods to T3](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types).