# Cannot use type with same underlying type in function parameter

Tags: go

I'm new to golang and not sure if the question title is accurate, but I will try to add a better description for the problem.

In `daos/model.go` I have a package with the following code:

```
type ActionType int
const (
    ActionTypeExecute ActionType = 0 + iota
    ActionTypeSelect
    ActionTypeInput
    ActionTypeClick
    ActionTypeWait
)
func ActionTypeFromString(s *string) (ActionType, error) {
    switch *s {
    case "execute":
        return ActionTypeExecute, nil
    case "select":
        return ActionTypeSelect, nil
    case "input":
        return ActionTypeInput, nil
    case "click":
        return ActionTypeClick, nil
    case "wait":
        return ActionTypeWait, nil
    }
    return 0, ErrInvalidActionTypeText
}
```

The purpose of `ActionTypeFromString` is to convert a string passed as param to an int.

In `actions/model.go` I have another package:

```
type ActionType string
const (
    ActionTypeExecute ActionType = "execute"
    ActionTypeSelect ActionType = "select"
    ActionTypeInput ActionType = "input"
    ActionTypeClick ActionType = "click"
    ActionTypeWait ActionType = "wait"
)
type NewAction struct {
    ActionType *ActionType `json:"type"`
}

func insertActionsFromScan(newActions []*NewAction) {
    for _, newAction := range newActions {

        actionTypeInt, err := models.ActionTypeFromString(newAction.ActionType)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    }
}
```

Compiling the code gives the following error and I'm not understanding why, since `newAction.ActionType` is a string

> cannot use newAction.ActionType (type *ActionType) as type *string in argument to models.ActionTypeFromString

Comment: The error is self-explanatory: `type ActionType string` introduces a new type. You have to cast to `* string`

Comment: @mkopriva that worked, I tried some conversions before posting the question, but not like this. Thank you, maybe add your comment as an answer

Comment: Check this out for a deeper understanding: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19334542/2117591

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The types `*string` and `*actions.ActionType` are not the same, `string` and `actions.ActionType` are also not the same. However they share the same underlying type which means you can convert one to the other. e.g. `(*string)(newAction.ActionType)`.

As mentioned by @Imaxd in the comments, you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19334952/965900) for more details.

Comment: you could mention this question which is related https://stackoverflow.com/q/19334542/2117591